# Location of Vijñana Nadis (discussed in Shiva Samhita)

Tags: yoga, hatha-yoga

In the Shiva Samhita it says, "Seated in Padmasana and away from human company, he should block the two Vijñana nadis with his fingers." **What I am trying to figure out is the location of the two Vijñana nadis in the body. Where is it suggesting to pinch?**

The text continues, "Perfection then manifests itself, blissful and pure. One can become an adept by means of this, so great effort should be put into it. Success is not far off for the man who practices it regularly. He is sure to gradually attain mastery of the air."

I am using the kindle edition of James Mallinson's translation of the Shiva Samhita. It is at location 861-865 (there are no page numbers in Kindle versions).

Comment: I believe its not tough nut to crack its nostrils. one should do kumbhaka..